# Mysql query optimization - using indexes

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, indexing

I have following queries:

```
select from `table` where `a`>0 order by `b` desc limit 0, 10
select from `table` where `a`<0 order by `b` desc limit 0, 10
```

I want them to run as fast as possible. Now the question is what's the best solution?

- create index for a, create index for b
- create multicolumn index for a, b
- create multicolumn index for b, a

My guess is that using multicolumn index would give the best results... but what's the correct order of columns? Will MySQL match against column `a` first and then `b`, or first `b` then `a`?

Thanks

Comment: Compound indexes will not help in this case.

Comment: What's the percenatge of rows in your table that are `a>0` and what for `a<0` ?

Answer (score 0):

Index on `(a,b)` should work fast.

Documentation says

> The index can also be used even if the ORDER BY does not match the index exactly, as long as all of the unused portions of the index and all the extra ORDER BY columns are constants in the WHERE clause.

Now if > 0, can be regarded as constant, as I think it should, then index (a,b) might work fast of all. Although you might wanna try ans see the explain plan.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html

Answer (score 0):

Theory is one thing, in practice you **always** have to benchmark.